# How can i prevent .txt file from being viewed directly?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, permissions, redirect, file-permissions

I have this Javascript code which will search into a .txt file called codes.txt

```js
                    $.get('codes.txt', function (contents) {
                        if (contents.includes($('#code').val())) {
                            validForm =true;
                        } else {
                            alert("Sorry!! That is not a valid code. Try again! Or email admin@apsoccer.hk");
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

I want .htaccess, permissions or any trick to make it used only by my server and not viewed directly like http://mysite/codes.txt

How can i do that?

Comment: You can’t, as long as you rely on reading the file contents on the client side. You will have to port this to the server, so that only the term to search for gets send there, and then based on whether or not that is found in the text file, the server-side script gives the appropriate response to the client-side script.

Comment: Or use a cloud storage service like firebase

Answer (score 3):

edit your .htaccess in order to accept reading file if accessed from AJAX only.

```
<Files "code.txt">
    SetEnvIfNoCase X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest ajax
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=ajax
</Files>
```

Comment: How can i set that to .txt files only??

Comment: the simplest solution is to create a folder like "config" and put there your files codes.txt  and .htaccess with code above... than call ajax from folder "config" like:  $.get('config/codes.txt', function (contents) {...}

Answer (score 1):

store `codes.txt` outside of the public directory (or use .htaccess to deny public access to it) and then use `$.get` to hit a server-sided script which returns the contents of the text file instead of hitting the text file itself. You could then add security to the server-sided script. (user permissions, CSRF protection etc.)